# MongoDB: Fazer projection de apenas um elemento de um array aninhado a outro array aninhado a um objeto

Tags: query, mongodb

Tenho a seguinte situação: preciso realizar uma query de um documento com uma projection que retorne apenas o primeiro elemento de uma lista. Só que esta lista está dentro de outra lista, e essa outra lista está dentro de um objeto que está dentro de outro objeto em um documento no MongoDB, mais ou menos como o exemplo a seguir:

```
    {
      "items": {
        "item": [
          {
            "items": {
              "item": [
                {
                  "cell": [
                    {
                      "value": "a"
                    },
                    {
                      "value": "b"
                    },
                    {
                      "value": "c"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Meu objetivo é fazer uma busca por **value : "a"** com uma projection que ignore os outros valores. Ou seja, minha projection deveria retornar isso:

```
    {
      "items": {
        "item": [
          {
            "items": {
              "item": [
                {
                  "cell": [
                    {
                      "value": "a"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

O problema é que eu já tentei todas as alternativas possíveis: usei $elemMatch, $ e $slice pra retornar apenas o primeiro elemento, mas não consigo montar uma query que faça isso por causa da complexidade do documento. Estou usando o MongoDB 3.2.

Se precisarem de mais informações eu atualizo aqui. De qualquer forma obrigado a todos desde já!

Answer (score -1):

```
db.getCollection('items').find({"item": {"items":{"item":{"cell":{"value":"a"}}}}})
```